# Need to populate an option/select from a database query based on data returned through jQuery

Tags: html, jquery, html-select

Here is the code - am sure it's something stupid and any help will be appreciated.

Data is being returned to this page through jQuery below.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
$(".uDL").click(function() {
    var target = $(this).attr("rel");
    $.ajax({
              url: "managesupervisorcasereview.php", 
                    type: "post",
                    data: {'action': 'get', 'scrid':target},
                    dataType: 'html',
                    success: function($data){
                            var v=$data;
                            //console.log(v);
                            var arr = v.split("~");

                            var $scr_raterid = arr[0];
                            $("#scrq1").val(arr[3]);
                            $("#scrq2").val(arr[4]);
                            $("#scrq3").val(arr[5]);
                            $("#scrq4").val(arr[6]);
                            
                            document.getElementById("scrid").value =target;
                                                            
                            if (arr[2] != "0000-00-00" && arr[2] != "") { 
            $("#scr_rating_date").datepicker( "setDate", Date.parse(arr[2]).setTimezone("UTC") );
                            }   
                            toggleaddnewupdatescr('Update');
                }
    });
    return false;
 });
});
```

HTML Page has a dropdown populated from a database table - it needs to be pre-populated if the earlier query returned a matching value which I am storing in $scr_raterid.

```
            <table id="ques1scr">
                <tr>
                    <td><strong>Rating Date:<strong></td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text"  id="scr_rating_date" name="scr_rating_date" />
                    </td>
                    <td><strong>Rater Name:</strong></td>
                    <td><select name="scr_raterid" id="scr_raterid" style="width: 200px;">
                            <option value="" > </option>
                            <?php
                                include 'common.php';
                                $sql1=mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT u.name, u.user_id  FROM user u 
  where u.is_active =  '1' and u.role='Trainer' and u.status = 'Active' order by u.name asc ");
                                while ($data=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql1))
                                  {
                            ?>
                            <option <?php 
                            if ($scr_raterid==$data['user_id']) echo 'selected="selected"';?>  value 
  ="<?php echo $data['user_id'] ?>">
                                <?php echo $data['name'];?>
                            </option>
                            <?php } ?>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                </tr>
             </table>
```

Comment: This is a bit confusing but php only runs on server not in browser. If you want to populate that select based on ajax request then you would return the needed data in the request to fill it in using javascript not php. Could be html returned or json data you use to create the options html

Comment: Thanks for responding, but I didn't understand - I am not familiar with json.

Comment: OK. Don't worry about that format then. If I understand correctly you want the `<option>` set based on query results in php. Then think of an empty `<select>` and you send back the html from server in ajax response to put in the select like `$('#mySelect').html(optionsHtmlFromAjaxResponse)`

Comment: I have a rater table with Rater IDs and names which allows user to select in the drop-down field.  If that rater was selected earlier it will be returned in the AJAX response and that just needs to be displayed in the drop-down field.

Comment: Do this web search *"ajax cascade select php"*. will find lots of results including some written and video tutorials. I don't think you understand the basics enough here how to work with ajax

Comment: I tried using $(#scr_raterid).val(arr[0]); in AJAX, but that didn't work either.  I think I need help with the php section of the code.  It is working for the other form fields where I am listing the options in the select drop-downs. but in this one where I am querying a table, instead of listing each option.  I did run the search you recommended, but most of those are for dependent select drop-downs, which doesn't apply in this case.  Appreciate your patience.

Comment: You don't want to set the value....you want to inject the html using `html()` and be sure to quote the selector string

Comment: That query php would and loop to generate the html would no longer be nested in parent page also

Comment: OK - let me research it further.  Thank you